# Cannot evaluate XPath on XMLDoc without placing it in the DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, tei

I have only been able to get result nodes from my DOM with XPath, which feels incorrect.

### Setup:

I am attempting to show a fragment of an XML Document (TEI/XML) on my HTML page. I have the URL of an XML Document and an XPath selector of the fragment. I thought I could `fetch()` the document and extract the piece I wanted like so:

```js
// Real values, for one case, 
// t.source = "https://centerfordigitalhumanities.github.io/Dunbar-books/The-Complete-Poems-TEI.xml"
// t.selector.value = "//div[@type='poem'][8]"

const sampleSource = await fetch(t.source)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(docStr => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(docStr, "application/xml"))

const poemText = sampleSource.evaluate(t.selector?.value, sampleSource, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)

textSample.innerHTML = poemText.snapshotItem(0).innerHTML
```

### No Result

Trying several different ways (changing `contextNode`, using `XPathSelector.evaluate()` instead of `XMLDoc.evaluate()`, and changing `XPathResult`) the result was always empty.

In frustration, I tried simpler and simpler selectors and discovered that `evaluate()` was only traversing my current HTML `document` despite making no references to it.

### The Workaround

It "works" to dump the XML doc into a hidden element on the page.

```js
const sampleSource = await fetch(t.source)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(docStr => hiddenElem.innerHTML = docStr)

const poemText = document.evaluate(t.selector?.value, hiddenElem, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)

textSample.innerHTML = poemText.snapshotItem(0).innerHTML
```

### Questions

1. Is this how it is supposed to work, that `evaluate()` only traverses `document`?
2. Is there a better practice than my workaround?

Comment: have you tried logging what `sampleSource` is after the last `.then()`?

Comment: `sampleSource` is an XMLDocument

Comment: Do you *know* that or do you *assume* that?

Comment: Thank you for checking. I can stop on a breakpoint (or `console.log()` out) that `typeof === "object"` and `sampleSource` is the `#document` I expect.

I can also use `sampleSource.querySelector()` to select the innards as well, it is only the XPath Selector that is not performing as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is a TEI document so its elements are in the namespace `http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0`, don't expect to use XPath 1 against an XML DOM document and a selector like `div` to select elements in any namespace, it exactly selects `div` elements in no namespace. To select elements in a namespace with XPath 1.0, you need to use the third argument of  `evaluate` and bind a prefix you can choose (like `tei`) to that namespace and use e.g. `//tei:div[@type='poem'][8]`:

```html
<script type=module>
const sampleSource = await fetch('https://centerfordigitalhumanities.github.io/Dunbar-books/The-Complete-Poems-TEI.xml')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(docStr => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(docStr, "application/xml"));

const poemText = sampleSource.evaluate(`//tei:div[@type='poem'][8]`, sampleSource, prefix => prefix === 'tei' ? 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0' : null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

console.log(poemText.snapshotItem(0).textContent);
</script>
```

With XPath 2 or 3, like Saxon-JS 2 for instance supports, you can bind a default element namespace and use an unqualified named like `div` to select elements in that namespace.

```html
<script src=https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js></script>

<script type=module>
    const sampleSource = await SaxonJS.getResource({ location : 'https://centerfordigitalhumanities.github.io/Dunbar-books/The-Complete-Poems-TEI.xml', type : 'xml' });


    const poemText = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`//div[@type='poem'][8]`, sampleSource, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0' });

    console.log(poemText.textContent);
</script>
```

There is no way in XPath 1.0, unless the DOM environment allows you to build a namespace less DOM (like Java with a non-namespace aware DocumentBuilder). But inside of a browser that is not the case, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of insight I was looking for. I will try it out and see if it does what I'm expecting.

Comment: This is the information I needed. I hadn't considered the inherited namespace prefixes on the things within. I appreciate the insight that XPath 1.0.